# Different stylesheet for different device

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-website

I have a question: how to automatically change website look based on device type? I know there is something like

```
@media screen and (max-width:720px){/*code for mobile here*/}
@media screen and (min-width:1280px) {/*code for PC here*/}
```

but I think it can cause problems on big resolution mobile devices and low resolution desktop monitors. 
So I wonder is there any way of changing css file/selecting exact part of css code based on device type, like smartphone, tablet or PC?

Anything that works will help. If something is not clear, I will try to explain it better. If I'm wrong, correct me.

Comment: "it can cause problems on big resolution mobile devices and low resolution desktop monitors" - in what way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use these:

```
// Large devices (desktops, less than 1200px)
 @media (max-width: 1199px) { ... }

 // Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px)
 @media (max-width: 991px) { ... }

 // Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)
 @media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

 // Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
 @media (max-width: 575px) { ... }
```

Comment: But what if you have tablet or smartphone with width about 1200px? How to switch to mobile version automaticlly?

Comment: Those are the standards, you can't handle any custom size on the world. Anyway, you can change the first max-width to whatever you find more reasonable than standards.

Try those queries I posted and you'll see that it "switches automatically", provided you have listed the right css styles into the curly braces.

Comment: BTW, have you ever seen a mobile with size greater than 1200px? If yes, it should display the standard css for desktops, no reason to make it change.